# Prove that $\frac{1\cdot3\cdot.....\cdot(2n+1)}{2\cdot4\cdot....\cdot(2n)}$ is strictly increasing and not bounded above

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $\frac{1\cdot3\cdot.....\cdot(2n+1)}{2\cdot4\cdot....\cdot(2n)}$ is strictly increasing and not bounded above. I started by trying $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1$, but the calculation won't cancel out nicely at the end, did I approach this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

We can drop the $1$ from the numerator without changing the value. Now both the denominator and number have equal number of terms (i.e., $n$ terms).

Now this fraction can be regarded as product of $n$ fractions $3/2$, $5/4$, $7/6$ etc upto $(2n+1)/(2n)$. All these terms are bigger than $1$. The next term will introduce one more term to the product which is again${}>1$.

So the sequence is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Using the inequality $\log x\ge{x-1\over x}$, we see

$$\begin{align}
\log{1\cdot3\cdots(2n+1)\over2\cdot4\cdots(2n)}&=\log{3\over2}+\log{5\over4}+\cdots+\log{2n+1\over2n}\\
&\ge{1/2\over3/2}+{1/4\over5/4}+\cdots+{1/(2n)\over(2n+1)/(2n)}\\
&={1\over3}+{1\over5}+\cdots+{1\over2n+1}
\end{align}$$

which, given the well known divergence of the harmonic series, implies the unboundedness of ${1\cdot3\cdots(2n+1)\over2\cdot4\cdots(2n)}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{2n+3}{2n+2}a_n>a_n$$

Comment: Only shows increasing, not bounded above.